# Can I sell a program developed in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recall a few years ago hearing that software developed in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition was required to be open source and couldn't be sold.

I was just revisiting the possibility of using it and couldn't find any reference to this limitation - does this rule still exist (did it ever?)

If someone could point out something official saying whether this is or isn't permissible I'd appreciate it. I've already searched for it and found nothing, which leads me to think that the person who told me this was mistaken and the rule never existed.

Comment: IntelliJ Community is under an Apache license, so I can't see why you couldn't sell a program developed in it. The most definite way to know is to ask them outright (or a lawyer) though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/license issues, not programming.

Comment: @mah - I hesitated to put it up, but I believe it's on-topic because it's about the legality of programs I've developed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition for anything, commercial or not. Similar question was asked here many times.
What you are confusing is *Ultimate edition for Open Source projects* and *Community Edition*.

Comment: I noticed that there's also enterprise versions of Ultimate. Suppose a few months from now, before releasing the program, I hire a few people to help me. Will it be legal for us to use the community edition still and sell it when we're done?

Comment: Usage of Community Edition is always legal, it is just a free software, no strings attached.

Comment: I'll accept what you say as true, just because I can't find anything that contradicts it.

Comment: Hi Meo. I was kind of a jerk a year ago. This is a perfect answer and I don't know why I didn't upvote it last year. I have remedied that now.